# how to configure 2.9.1 in org.scala-sbt#sbt_2.9.1;0.12.3

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying a very simple sbt example; when I compile it with sbt, and always get the following error:

```
    org.scala-sbt#sbt_2.9.1;0.12.3: not found
```

I found a build.properties file under project folder, where I could change the 0.12.3 part; for example, after I changed it to 0.11.3, it will succeed until another inompatible issue; However, I want to know how to change sbt_2.9.1 to, say, sbt_2.9.2; I don't find a configuration file, and even I update the sbt to the latest version 0.12.3, still no luck.

my build.sbt file:

```
organization := "com.typesafe.slick"

name := "slick-examples"

version := "1.0.1-RC1"

scalaVersion := "2.10.1"

scalacOptions += "-deprecation"
```

anyone please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Scala version sbt is using internally and the one used for your project are totally independent. Which sbt launcher are you using? Make sure you are using an sbt.version property that works for your sbt launcher.

Again, no need to configure the Scala version for your project at that level. Write a build.sbt file and set scalaVersion to, e.g. 2.10.1 (assuming you use sbt 0.12.x): `scalaVersion := 2.10.1`

Comment: edited with build.sbt file, there is indeed scalaVersion sepecified, but not working.